# Time complexity of special string sequence

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Problem: There is a special string sequence where the n-th string is equal to:  previous string + "0" + previous string

S1 = 1 ,  S2 = 101, S3 = 1010101, S4 = 101010101010101

I would like to ask what is the minimum time complexity in getting the k-th character of the n-th string. Can I do so without finding every prior elements in the string sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is hard to see a pattern when you are using 1 an 0, so let's use letters instead.

S1 = abc S2 = abc-d-abc S3 = abcdabc-d-abcdabc

the pattern is a bit more obvious now. You always have S1 + d + S1 + d + ... + S1.

The length is S1.length * n + (n - 1). Pattern length is 4. So the length doesn't really matter, the k-th character is (S1 + d)[k % 4] where k < length.

The time complexity is O(1) if you are not generating new strings.